# checking for a char in my string is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a list with contact numbers and whatsapp's group IDs, and i want to make two lists, one for each type of data.

im using the 'in' keyword to check for the '+' that every number has, so i can place them in a separate list, but its not working.

ctts.txt list are like this:

```
ctts =['contactName', ' +559999999-9999'], ['groupName', ' ABCDEFabcdef123456']]
```

```
def separateNumbersFromIDs():
    lNumbers = []
    lGroups = []
    for i in ctts:
        if "+" in i[1:]:
            lNumeros.append(i)
        else:
            lGrupos.append(i)
           
    return lNumbers, lGroups
```

i got no error at all, but all of the elements goes to the lGroups list (even the ones who shouldn't), so basically the  "+" in i[1:] is not working.

Comment: Assuming `ctts` is a list of lists, `i` is a sublist, whereas `i[1:]` is a slice of that list, which is also a list. That would return the same result as `'+' in ['+1234']` (i.e. `False`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get the string from the sublist. Also you declare the lists in English, but are trying to append to their Spanish names.

```
ctts =[['contactName', ' +559999999-9999'], ['groupName', ' ABCDEFabcdef123456']]

def separateNumbersFromIDs(ctts):
    lNumbers = []
    lGroups = []
    for i in ctts:
        if "+" in i[1:].pop():
            lNumbers.extend(i)
        else:
            lGroups.extend(i)
           
    return lNumbers, lGroups

print(separateNumbersFromIDs(ctts))

(['contactName', ' +559999999-9999'], ['groupName', ' ABCDEFabcdef123456'])
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, didnt know about the .pop function.

i wasn't messing up in the appending tho, i just translated the lists's names to make this post.